# JSTL tags return null/empty in Javascript calls and HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, string, jsp, jstl

This is a really confusing error, as it crops up in some of the webpages that I'm creating, but not in others, although syntactically the elements are identical.

For example, this doesn't show up:

```
            <main:uiInputBox
                onDarkBG="${hasDarkBG}"
                name="questionTitle1"
                onblur="pollUpdateQuestion(false, false, true, this);"
                defaultValue="&lt;${field['POLL_FIELD_ENTER_QUESTION']}&gt;"
                styleWidth="280px">
            </main:uiInputBox>
```

Where the tag `${field['POLL_FIELD_ENTER_QUESTION']}` should return the string "enter question". What I don't understand is that the tag returns the string normally in the JSP file, but now when it's in the HTML descriptor.

Another error is that in javascript if I have a function like this:

It prints out the literal string `"${field['POLL_FIELD_CHOICE']}"`, and not the element that it's representing. Ex:

```
template.find('h2').text('${field["POLL_FIELD_CHOICE"]} ');
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where is your Javascript? Is it in a separate file? Also, what is `field`? Is it a `Map`? If so, what type is the key to the `Map`? Is it a `String`?

Comment: Does this differ on pages within the same server, or between applications in differing server environments? And what version(s) of JSP servlet engines are we talking about?

Comment: sorry, I'll elaborate. "field" is a map that is <string, string>. The javascript is inside the .JSP file. I've checked to see that the key-value pair exists, and it does. But on javascript it returns empty/null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to the first problem of EL not being resolved in a custom tag, that's not [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) (it are those `<c:xxx>` tags). That's EL (those `${}` things).

You seem to be using EL in a custom tag. The `<main:xxx>` does not belong to any JSP standard tag library (look, that's what JSTL stands for). To get EL in custom tags to work as well, you need to ensure of the following:

- The `web.xml` must be declared as *at least* Servlet 2.4, which implies JSP 2.0 where this feature is supported.

  ```
  <web-app 
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
      version="2.4">
  ```
- The `.tld` file of the `<main:xxx>` taglib must be declared as *at least* JSP 2.0, where the `<rtexprvalue>` attribute is supported.

  ```
  <taglib 
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd" 
      version="2.0">
  ```
- The `defaultValue` attribute in the `.tld` file of the `<main:uiInputBox>` must be marked with `<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>` to enable the support runtime expressions (the EL, those `${}` things).

  ```
  <attribute>
      <name>defaultValue</name>
      <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
  </attribute>
  ```

---

As to the second problem of EL not being resolved in a JavaScript file, well, the explanation is pretty simple: EL in template text like that runs in JSP (2.0 or newer) files with `.jsp` extension only. There are several ways to get it to work anyway:

- Rename `.js` to `.jsp` and add the following line to top of the page (best solution):

  ```
  <%@page contentType="text/javascript" %>
  ```
- Put that piece of JS in an inline `<script>` of the JSP page instead (not recommend since that's generally seen as a poor practice).
- Map `*.js` on the JSP servlet in `web.xml` (not recommended, it tight-couples your webapp to the servletcontainer's specific JspServlet which may not necessarily be mapped on the servlet name of `jsp`).

  ```
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

Comment: I tried your suggestion (the best solution) for the second problem, and the string is no longer read as a literal. instead, callingthe object from the map returns a blank.

Comment: Then the map is empty at that point. Is it been put in request scope instead of session/application scope or so? You might want to bring a servlet which is responsible for creating the map in front of that first. Or at least whoever is responsible for putting that map in request scope.